# Filter in formbuilder with querybuilder (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, query-builder, formbuilder

p is profile and u is user. Each user has one or more profiles. I want to filter one profile from each user who have more than 10 points. But I want to keep only one profile of each user that meets the condition.
I need that after the join only one value is taken for each user that meets the condition.

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->Join(User::class, 'u')
                        ->Where('u.point > 10')
                        ->andWhere('u.id = p.admin');

            },
```

This code "works" but it returns all the profiles and I only want one for each user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but $query->getSingleResult() returns only one result.

If you want to choose a specific profile you have to add another where with the condition needed.